# Is there a way to inhibit databinding updating in INVISIBLE (or GONE) views?

Tags: android-databinding

I am using android databinding to update views, and also to choose which views should be shown.

```xml
<include layout="@layout/type1_layout"
    android:visibility="@{data.type == 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    app:data="@{data}" />

<include layout="@layout/type2_layout"
    android:visibility="@{data.type == 2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    app:data="@{data}" />
```

The problem with this method is that both layouts exist all the time and will be updated when data changes. This could be a performance problem, and could also cause trouble if the data `type2_layout` depends on only exists when `data.type == 2` (although admittedly this is somewhat mitigated by automatic null handling).

If `data.type` doesn't change for the lifetime of the view, I can use `ViewStub`s which only create the actual view when becoming visible, but if the value can change after the view is shown that doesn't help.

So is there a way to either have a `ViewStub` deflate (somehow handling the interaction with databinding) or to temporarily turn off databinding for a `GONE` view?